# Count records from two tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join, count

Suppose I have these MySql tables:

**TABLE_PEOPLE**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Albert |
| 3 | Joanna |
| 4 | Mike |
| 5 | Norton |

**TABLE_COLOR**

| id | people_id | colors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Green |
| 2 | 1 | Red |
| 3 | 3 | Yellow |
| 4 | 3 | Blue |
| 5 | 2 | Green |
| 6 | 4 | Red |
| 7 | 5 | Grey |
| 8 | 3 | White |
| 9 | 4 | Black |
| 10 | 1 | Black |

**TABLE_FRUIT**

| id | people_id | fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Lemon |
| 2 | 2 | Apple |
| 3 | 3 | Tangerine |
| 4 | 5 | Orange |
| 5 | 2 | Banana |
| 6 | 1 | Apple |
| 7 | 5 | Lemon |
| 8 | 2 | Orange |
| 9 | 3 | Watermelon |
| 10 | 4 | Banana |

What I'd like to have is a query with numbers of occurrences of colors and fruits for each person:

**RESULTS**
| name| count_colors | count_fruits |
|:----:|:----:|:-------:|
|John|3|2|
|Albert|1|3|
|Joanna|3|2|
|Mike|2|1|
|Norton|1|1|

I'm trying to use this query, but it returns some inconsistent numbers:

```
SELECT
TABLE_PEOPLE.name AS name,
COUNT(TABLE_COLOR.people_id) AS count_colors,
COUNT(TABLE_FRUIT.people_id) AS count_fruits
FROM TABLE_PEOPLE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_COLOR ON TABLE_COLOR.people_id = TABLE_PEOPLE.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_FRUIT ON TABLE_FRUIT.people_id = TABLE_PEOPLE.id
GROUP BY TABLE_PEOPLE.id
ORDER BY TABLE_PEOPLE.id
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current query is that you are using the COUNT function to count the number of occurrences of people_id in TABLE_COLOR and TABLE_FRUIT. However, this will not give you the correct result because the COUNT function will only return the number of non-NULL values, and since you are using LEFT JOIN, all of the people_id values will be non-NULL, so COUNT will always return the same value for each person.

To fix this issue, you can use a subquery in your SELECT clause to count the number of occurrences of colors and fruits for each person:

```
SELECT
  TABLE_PEOPLE.name AS name,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_COLOR WHERE TABLE_COLOR.people_id = TABLE_PEOPLE.id) AS count_colors,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_FRUIT WHERE TABLE_FRUIT.people_id = TABLE_PEOPLE.id) AS count_fruits
FROM TABLE_PEOPLE
ORDER BY TABLE_PEOPLE.id
```

This will return the correct number of occurrences of colors and fruits for each person.

Answer (score 0):

You should join to subqueries which find the various counts:

```sql
SELECT
    p.name,
    COALESCE(c.cnt, 0) AS count_colors,
    COALESCE(f.cnt, 0) AS count_fruits
FROM TABLE_PEOPLE p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM TABLE_COLOR
    GROUP BY people_id
) c
    ON c.people_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM TABLE_FRUIT
    GROUP BY people_id
) f
    ON f.people_id = p.id
ORDER BY
    p.id;
```

Your exact problem is happening because of the double join to the colors and fruits table, which results in multiplication of records.